# Why does this primality condition work? $p \ge 5 \in \Bbb P \Leftrightarrow \gcd(k,p+k)=1\ \forall k \in [3..p-1]$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, primality-test

I was playing with the rules of [Rowland's prime-generating sequence](https://oeis.org/A106108) to learn how it works, and doing some tests I noticed that the following condition works as a primality condition, probably it is very easy to prove but I can not see the reason why it works:

> $$p \ge 5 \in \Bbb P \Leftrightarrow \gcd(k,p+k)=1\ \forall k \in [3..p-1]$$

For instance $11$ is prime because for the intervals $[3,10]$ and $[14,21]$ holds: $$\gcd(3,14)=1,\gcd(4,15)=1,...,\gcd(10,21)=1$$

And for instance $25$ is not prime because $\gcd(3,28)=1,\gcd(4,29)=1$ (up to that point is fine) but then $\gcd(5,30)=5$, not $1$, so $25$ is not prime.

I would like to ask the following questions:

> 1. Is that observation correct or there is a counterexample?
> 2. What property of the prime numbers is behind that rule? I am sure this is quite simple but I really do not see it. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, $\gcd(x,y)=\gcd(x,y-x)$ (this fact is the basis for the Euclidean algorithm).  In particular, $\gcd(k,p+k)=\gcd(k,p)$.  So your condition is just saying that no $k$ between $3$ and $p-1$ has a nontrivial common factor with $p$.  If $p$ is prime, this is obviously true.  Conversely, if your condition holds, then $p$ cannot have any factors between $3$ and $p-1$.  The only nontrivial factor $p$ could have is $2$, but then $p/2$ is also a factor, so this is only possible if $p/2=2$ or $p/2=1$, which contradicts your assumption that $p\geq 5$.

More generally, by a similar argument, if $p>n^2$, then $\gcd(k,p+k)=1$ for $k=n,\dots,p-1$ iff $p$ is prime.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer! that is right, it is the basis for the Euclidean algorithm.